Examples of Chern-Weil theory
I am learning Chern-Weil theory using Loring W. Tu's book  "Differential Geometry: Connections, Curvature, and Characteristic Classes". I like the book, but it is mostly concentrated on theoretical part and doesn't provide many examples. There is a computation of Euler classes of oriented surfaces (as an illustration of Gauss-Bonnet theorem), but that's it.
I would like to see in detail how one can actually compute characteristic classes using Chern-Weil theory for some specific bundles. For example, how does one compute Chern classes of tautological bundles  over complex projective space (or complex Grassmannians)? Or Euler classes and Pontryagin classes of some (not too complicated) higher dimensional manifolds. For example, $S^2\times S^2$.
I think that I understand what is going on in theory, but when it comes to computations, I am lost. The main issue is that I don't understand how one would pick a convenient connection to compute characteristic classes. When we have some "good" Riemannian metric (like on $S^n$) we can choose Levi-Civita connection associated to it,  but what to do in the general case?
Are there any references that contain examples and problems of this type?

Some of us do not own or know the book. What examples and applications does he include?

There is a computation of Euler classes of oriented surfaces, I couldn't find any other examples in the book. I edited question to elaborate on what I want.

To answer your question carefully would require hours of typing. But you should learn about the canonical (so-called Chern) connection on a hermitian vector bundle on a complex manifold. This is the analogue of the Levi-Civita connection on a Riemannian manifold. For the Chern classes of the universal sub- (and quotient) bundles on the complex Grassmannian, I would also naturally use the language and notation of moving frames — as Chern did in his original papers on the subject.
